# How to save image using Python

Tags: python

I have an image file decoded by base64.
Now, I want to save the image file to the specified directory.

the directory is described as image_dir_path

```
image_dir_path = '/images/store/'
image_file = base64.b64decode(image_file)
```

How can I save the image_file to image_dir_path?

I tried `shutil.copy(image_file, image_dir_path)`, but it doesn't work for my case.

I'm sorry I coundn't find the question like this.

Comment: Have you tried using Pillow or PIL?

Comment: I tried to use PIL, but unfortunately could not find any ways to save the image on specific directory...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can write any content to a file with a file object and its write method. As an example, let's grab some base64 encoded data from the web:

```
import base64, urllib

decoded = base64.b64decode(urllib.urlopen("http://git.io/vYT4p").read())    
with open('/tmp/31558315.png', 'w') as handle:
    handle.write(decoded)
```

You should be able to open the file under `/tmp/31558315.png` as a regular image.

Comment: Thanks! It worked I got [Errno 21] Is a directory: 'images/store' though.

Comment: @ReiKudo, Error 21 [means](http://www.virtsync.com/c-error-codes-include-errno) *is a directory*. You seemed to write something, but it fails, because the target is a directory, which is not expected at this point.

Comment: I got it wrong totally. Error occurred since I tried to open directory. Thank you @miku.